# R highlight only one bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight "Prime" element only in the bar plot. However, when there is no "Prime" element in particular column, this bar plot highlight all the bar (which it should not be highlighted).

This is my R code for further information:

```
test.df <- data.frame(replace_punct = c("Prime", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured"), pos = c("Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured"), spelling_corr = c("Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Prime", "Prime"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

replace_punct_bar <- ggplot(data=test.df, aes(x = replace_punct, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)), fill = ifelse(replace_punct == "Prime", "Highlighted", "Normal"))) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + geom_bar() + labs(title = "Replace punctuation freq", y = "Percent", x = "Status") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.6), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed") + theme(legend.position="none")

pos_bar <- ggplot(data=test.df, aes(x = pos, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)), fill = ifelse(pos == "Prime", "Highlighted", "Normal"))) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + geom_bar() + labs(title = "Part of speech freq", y = "Percent", x = "Status") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.6), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed") + theme(legend.position="none")

spelling_corr_bar <- ggplot(data=test.df, aes(x = spelling_corr, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)), fill = ifelse(spelling_corr == "Prime", "Highlighted", "Normal"))) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + geom_bar() + labs(title = "Spelling correction freq", y = "Percent", x = "Status") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.6), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed") + theme(legend.position="none")

grid.arrange(replace_punct_bar, pos_bar, spelling_corr_bar, ncol=3)
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: thanks @r2evans for pointing this out. I am new in posting question on stackoverflow

Comment: The easy solution is not to map any aesthetic to fill in `pos_bar`, and set the color manually in `geom_bar()`.  Or do you not know in advance which plots will have a "Prime" element and you need a general solution?

Comment: If it is solved, you can mark your answer as accepted. No need to edit the title as solved

Answer (score 1):

You can add a scale, like:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Highlighted" = "purple","Not Normal" = "grey"))
```

in every plot, the result would be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @vinícius-félix ! I only change "Not Normal" to "Normal" to get the visualization that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea from @vinícius-félix answer. Here is the updated code on how the bar plot that I wanted it to be visualized.

```
test.df <- data.frame(replace_punct = c("Prime", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured"), pos = c("Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured"), spelling_corr = c("Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Not Measured", "Prime", "Prime"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

replace_punct_bar <- ggplot(data=test.df, aes(x = replace_punct, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)), fill = ifelse(replace_punct == "Prime", "Highlighted", "Normal"))) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + geom_bar() + labs(title = "Replace punctuation freq", y = "Percent", x = "Status") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.6), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed") + theme(legend.position="none") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Highlighted" = "#f8766d","Normal" = "#00bfc4"))

pos_bar <- ggplot(data=test.df, aes(x = pos, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)), fill = ifelse(pos == "Prime", "Highlighted", "Normal"))) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + geom_bar() + labs(title = "Part of speech freq", y = "Percent", x = "Status") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.6), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed") + theme(legend.position="none") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Highlighted" = "#f8766d","Normal" = "#00bfc4"))

spelling_corr_bar <- ggplot(data=test.df, aes(x = spelling_corr, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)), fill = ifelse(spelling_corr == "Prime", "Highlighted", "Normal"))) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + geom_bar() + labs(title = "Spelling correction freq", y = "Percent", x = "Status") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.6), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed") + theme(legend.position="none") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Highlighted" = "#f8766d","Normal" = "#00bfc4"))

grid.arrange(replace_punct_bar, pos_bar, spelling_corr_bar, ncol=3)
```

I hope this code help anybody that facing the problem like mine. Thanks!